# How to force SVG path to be relative

Tags: inkscape, svg, affinity-designer

First off - I have very little experience working with SVGs beyond using them as image files.

I have an SVG file I got from a third-party vendor.  Whenever I save the SVG, it sets the width and height to 1146px.  If I remove those attributes, embed the SVG in my html file with a set width/height of 16px, the svg is 16x16, but the path is still the full 1146px wide.

I have tried exporting the file from Affinity Designer with the Export Setting "Use relative coordinates" checked - no luck.  I have also tried exporting from Inkscape 1.2 with the Preference: Input/Output > SVG output > Path data > Path string format: Relative setting.  Also no luck.

Looking at the raw SVG code, it looks like the path coordinates aren't being changed.  Any advice as to how I can make this SVG actually responsive?

Here's the SVG, run through SVGOMG:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="1146" height="1146" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2">
  <path d="M572.8 1145.7A573 573 0 0 1 0 572.8 573 573 0 0 1 572.8 0h429.7c79 0 143.2 64.2 143.2 143.2v429.6a573 573 0 0 1-572.9 572.9z" style="fill:#148fcc;fill-rule:nonzero"/>
  <path d="M564.3 856.5c7.3 4.6 18.3 3.4 23.2-3.5L781 602l45.2-58.4c11-13.8 0-33.2-18.3-33.2H516.5l71-202.9c2.5-6.9 0-13.8-6.1-18.3-7.4-4.6-18.4-3.5-23.3 3.4L364.7 544.7l-45.3 58.5c-11 13.7 0 33.2 18.4 33.2h291.3l-71 202.9c-2.4 5.7 0 13.7 6.2 17.2z" style="fill:#fff;fill-rule:nonzero"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Have you tried just removing the width and height from the SVG itself? I'm not sure I understand "the path is still really wide".

Comment: Yes, I've tried that.  When I investigate the svg in the browser's dev tools, the highlighting box surrounding the svg element is 16px wide.  When I hover over the first path node, the highlighting box surrounding that path element is still 1145px-ish wide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a ['viewBox'-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox). Try adding `viewBox="0 0 1146 1146"` to the <svg>-element. You may also want to look into the ['preserveAspectRatio'-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio).

Comment: I explicitly told it to remove the viewbox.  Adding it back and adding the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute totally fixed the problem.  Thanks!